# PInvoke SetStdHandle for use with Unmanaged dll peculiarity based on build configuration (VisualStudio)

Tags: c#, pinvoke, stdio

I'm experiencing some odd behavior when attempting to PInvoke SetStdHandle() to redirect stdout/stderr from an unmanaged DLL.  Namely, with a given DLL it works ONLY under Debug builds (not Release).

The relevant code looks like this:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SetStdHandle(int device, IntPtr handle);

    const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
    const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;

    static System.IO.FileStream outFileStream;
    static System.IO.FileStream errFileStream;
    public static void TestStdRedirect()
    {
        outFileStream = System.IO.File.Open("C:\\stdout.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        if (0 == SetStdHandle(-11, outFileStream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("HANDLE REASSIGNMENT FAILED!");
        errFileStream = System.IO.File.Open("C:\\stderr.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        if (0 == SetStdHandle(-12, errFileStream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("HANDLE REASSIGNMENT FAILED!");
    }

    public static void EndTestStdRedirect()
    {
        Console.OpenStandardOutput().Flush();
        Console.OpenStandardError().Flush();
        outFileStream.Flush();
        outFileStream.Close();
        errFileStream.Flush();
        errFileStream.Close();
    }
```

Now, when I do the following it *always* works (regardless of Release or Debug build) - the print statements are redirected to c:\stdout.txt and c:\stderr.txt as expected.

```
        TestStdRedirect();
        byte[] buf = Console.OutputEncoding.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ") Start Test StdOut" + Console.Out.NewLine);
        Console.OpenStandardOutput().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        buf = Console.OutputEncoding.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ") Start Test StdErr" + Console.Out.NewLine);
        Console.OpenStandardError().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        EndTestStdRedirect();
```

However, doing the following:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("SomeDLL.dll")]
    static extern void FxnFromUnmanagedDLL();

    TestStdRedirect();
    FxnFromUnmanagedDLL();
    EndTestStdRedirect();
```

where FxnFromUnmanagedDLL outputs to stdout/stderr via fprintf, the output gets redirected to file *only* when the project is built as "Debug."  If it's built as Release, the output goes straight to the Visual Studio output panel.

...In other words, this:

```
    TestStdRedirect();
    FxnFromUnmanagedDLL();
    byte[] buf = Console.OutputEncoding.GetBytes("blah" + Console.Out.NewLine);
    Console.OpenStandardOutput().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    EndTestStdRedirect();
```

would redirect "blah" to the file, but leave the unmanaged DLL's output going to console.  I've Googled and Googled and can't seem to figure out what's going on; my first thought was that the DLL was doing something funky like freopening or reassigning the streams somewhere, but I can't find anything to that effect (I do have access to the unmanaged DLL's source code).

Thanks in advance for your ideas...

Comment: This falls squarely into the "what if I'm not the only one calling SetStdHandle?" category.  You're not.  Anything in the Output window usually gets there through OutputDebugString() btw.

Comment: The DLL most definitely isn't calling SetStdHandle - it's unix code that was ported to Windows (by me).  Anything else?

Comment: Unix code that doesn't use the CRT?  Unlikely.  Anything else?

Comment: Sorry?  Don't understand the question: "anything else" - I've looked everywhere I could think of, thus the post above :P

Comment: I'm also having problems where the unmanaged dll output is making it to the VS Output window, but I can't seem to tap into it myself. Idk about you, but in my case it's a MinGW compiled C dll, which it seems can cause problems in this scenario. I haven't been able to find out much more. Were you ever able to get this working correctly?

Comment: @HansPassant are you saying that the reason the Visual Studio output window is picking up the unmanaged stdout is because the VS environment is using OutputDebugString() to get it or something in the dll? I'm in the same boat where I'm calling into the unmanaged dll via cdecl dllimport methods that I added to interface with what used to be strictly a command line app. Are you suggesting that there's something that can be done on the dll side to make this work?

Comment: Honestly can't recall as this was nearly a decade ago, however I almost always make a point of coming back & answering my own questions once I do find a solution, so my guess is that I didn't.